# Notebook contents changed upon re-opening

Tags: files-and-directories

Cross-posted in http://tieba.baidu.com/p/4439694061

I was so puzzled that why in *Mathematica* after I saved the nb file and when I opened it again the contents changed totally?

Another point that puzzled me a lot is that when I opened another nb file it showed:
[image]

and after I clicked "Enable Dynamics",it showed:

[image]

So in a word this nb file can't be opened, that is why?

Comment: Dude, let's have a chat here, in Chinese: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37664/dcydhb

Comment: Well, this is amusing. It looks like you have saved the welcome dialog to an untrusted folder. However, it can be opened. This dialog with the title and three buttons **is** the notebook you are opening.